# Is it possible to intercept the click handler in links of WEBUI's, and add a custom click action?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Say there's a custom link embedded in a WebUIView, and I would want to redirect a user not to Safari but to a different screen in the app.  Is it possible to change the click handler for that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) to the webView and use the [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) method to detect the links you want a return `NO`.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     if ([[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://www.customurl.com"]) {
         // Do something
         return NO;
     } else {
         return YES;
     }
}
```

You may also want to check the `navigationType` against [`UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW22).